# Entity Framework error - "Type argument 'Namespace...EntityName' does not satisfy the 'Class' constraint for the type 'TEntity'."

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I have the following two tables defined...

```
CREATE TABLE [LogLevel] (
  [Id] int primary key
  ,[Name] nvarchar(50) not null
  ,[Enabled] bit not null default (0)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Log] (
  [Id] bigint identity(1,1) primary key
  ,[LogLevel] int not null foreign key references [LogLevel]([Id])
  ,[On] datetimeoffset not null default (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
  ,[Summary] nvarchar(100)
  ,[Details] nvarchar(MAX)
)
```

After creating a fresh endity model, I add the two tables above.  When I try to build I get the following errors...

Type argument 'Inxsol.CommandPlan.Data.Model.Log.LogLevel' does not satisfy the 'Class' constraint for type parameter 'TEntity'.

Value of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference(Of Inxsol.CommandPlan.Data.Model.LogLevel)' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference(Of Inxsol.CommandPlan.Data.Model.Log.LogLevel)'.

Value of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference(Of Inxsol.CommandPlan.Data.Model.Log.LogLevel)' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference(Of Inxsol.CommandPlan.Data.Model.LogLevel)'.

Maximum number of errors has been exceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, hopefully someone else can post a better answer, but apparently the fit has something to do with the table [LogLevel]'s name or the table [Log]'s name... in either case, renaming them to [DiagnosticLog] and [DiagnosticLogLevel] resolved the issue at hand.